# Postgres 9.4, replication slots, doesn't work failover master

Tags: postgresql, replication, failover

I've installed postgres master and slave nodes by this manual:

**At the master (10.0.0.1)**:

```
sudo -u postgres initdb -D /data/postgres/main
```

Change postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 2
logging_collector = on
max_wal_senders = 5
```

Add record for replication to pg_hba.conf:

```
host replication replica 10.0.0.2/32 md5
```

Then start postgres

```
service postgresql start
```

Create replication user:

```
CREATE USER replica WITH REPLICATION ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '123456';
```

And add replication slot:

```
SELECT pg_create_physical_replication_slot('standby_slot');
```

**At the slave (10.0.0.2)**:

```
pg_basebackup -h 10.0.0.1 -U replica -D /db/postgres/main -X s -P
```

Change state to standby in postgresql.conf:

```
hot_standby = on
```

Add recovery.conf:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.0.0.1 port=5432 user=replica password=123456'
primary_slot_name = 'standby_slot'
trigger_file = 'trigger'
```

Start standby:

```
service postgresql start
```

So, replication is working fine. If I create database, it will appear both at the master and the slave.

If slave is going down and then starting, all changes come there. It all fine too.

But I have problem if master is down. When it stops, I create trigger file at the slave. Then I create another database at the slave, which now is primary. After that I start master, trigger file remove automatically, recovery.conf rename to recovery.done automatically too. Ok. But how to synchronize changes from slave (new primary) to master (old primary)?

I found that I've got to do these four steps:

**At the master:**

Stop postgres:

```
service postgresql stop
```

**At the slave:**

Switch backup mode on:

```
SELECT pg_backup_start('backup', true);
```

Then rsync new data from slave to master.

And then switch backup mode off:

```
SELECT pg_backup_stop();
```

After last step I get message

```
NOTICE: WAL archiving is not enabled; you must ensure that all required WAL segments are copied through other means to complete the backup
```

And then if I start master it doesn't start with log message:

```
FATAL: could not locate required checkpoint record
```

I don't understand, how to get new data at the master and make it primary again.

So at the future I plan to install pgpool2 for balancing and failover, but test installing did not work because I don't know, how this mechanism should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just jump back to the old master, as it is said [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/warm-standby-failover.html):

> Once failover to the standby occurs, there is only a single server in
>   operation. This is known as a degenerate state. The former standby is
>   now the primary, but the former primary is down and might stay down.
>   To return to normal operation, a standby server must be recreated,
>   either on the former primary system when it comes up, or on a third,
>   possibly new, system.

For this, you need a `recovery.conf` on the old master.  This should be nearly the same as the present one, only the connection has to point elsewhere.

Comment: So, I tried to make my old primary as standby. I did '/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_basebackup -h 10.0.0.2 -U replica -D /db/postgres/main -X s -P' to get the base contents and config files. Then I renamed recovery.done to recovery.conf, and I changed host-address at line primary_conninfo in the recovery.conf. Also I changed IP-address in the pg_hba.conf. After I started old master I still have no replication relation between two servers. If I drop some database on the new primary, I don't see changes on the old one

Comment: @user2627744 Do any errors pop up in the logs?

Comment: yes, it told me about absent replication slot. I added it by 'SELECT pg_create_physical_replication_slot('standby_slot')' at new primary and replication now work. So, as I understood, now I can make old master primary again by repeating my actions: stop new primary, touch trigger at old primary, pg_basebackup from old primary to new primary, edit config files, add replication slot and start new primary as standby again. I hope pgpool can do it without errors..

Comment: Great!  What I was not sure about was if the replication slot itself is replicated - apparently, you have to create it after failover.